# how to toggle div with another div

Tags: html, css

How do I solve this using css.
[image]

When I expand the contents in menu menu expand like second picture. This is my css

```
.contents {
    /*margin-left: 165px;*/
    /*margin-top: 60px;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 120px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and this is my html with contents.

```
<div class="contents" id="subContents">

</div>
```

I tried with position 'relative' but it doesn't works for me.
By using z-index there's a problem like this.
[image]
http://jsfiddle.net/ssaranga/o7sh1j0f/

Comment: work with z-index , or position fixed on the menu

Comment: Regarding your last attached picture: I thought that's what you wanted. At this point, it's not clear what you want to achieve. I reiterate: please make a demo (e.g. jsfiddle) to clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it is to add the `z-index` property to your toggle menu class and assign the highest value to it, according to how many stacked elements you have.

`z-index` specifies the stack order of an element. Different browsers have different max-min values.

The advantage of using a number larger than the actual stacked elements is that you don't have to go back and change the `z-index` value when you want to add more elements.

Note that z-index only works on positioned elements.

For example, you could do something like:

```
.toggle-menu{

position:relative
z-index: 999;

}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with using 9999 as a value, depends on the context. Note that by using 2, if you then need additional layers inbetween...you need to change the stacking again. A (albeit very) high number provides leeway

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana are you assigning it to the right div? Please make a demo (like a fiddle) so we can see that clearly.

Comment: menu is come top. but top contents in the other div cannot access.

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana please show the css and html of both divs or make a demo.

Answer (score 0):

The positioning is not your problem, it's the fact that your menu div is shown in the background.

You have html elements stacked on top of each other, and will have to work with the [CSS z-index propert](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) to adjust the element on the z-axis.

Comment: where did i use z-index

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana Your issue is that you haven't used the property. Read on the link and you will get a feeling of how it works.

Comment: menu is come top. but top contents in the other div cannot access

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana please show the css and html of both divs or make a demo.

Comment: @SarangaSachinthana I'm sorry, but posting a picture is of very little help. We need a demo or at least the html of your page!

Comment: try with redusing page width

Comment: dont consider about blue color div